Firebase Phone Authentication Error: FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/internal-error)
I'm trying to implement Firebase phone authentication in my chrome web extension.
Everything works fine on the web, but when implementing it in a web extension, I am encountering the following error:
PhoneAuth.js:
Error sending OTP: FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/internal-error).
Here is the code I’m using for Firebase phone authentication:
javascript

import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { auth } from './firebaseConfig';
import { RecaptchaVerifier, signInWithPhoneNumber, PhoneAuthProvider, signInWithCredential } from 'firebase/auth';

const PhoneAuth = () => {
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState('');
  const [otp, setOtp] = useState('');
  const [verificationId, setVerificationId] = useState(null);
  const [error, setError] = useState('');
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  const setupRecaptcha = () => {
    if (!window.recaptchaVerifier) {
      window.recaptchaVerifier = new RecaptchaVerifier(auth, 'recaptcha-container', {
        'size': 'invisible', // Invisible reCAPTCHA
        'callback': (response) => {},
        'expired-callback': () => {
          console.log('reCAPTCHA expired.');
        }
      });
    }
  };

  const sendOtp = async () => {
    try {
      setError('');
      setMessage('');
      setupRecaptcha();
      const appVerifier = window.recaptchaVerifier;
      const formattedPhoneNumber = `+${phoneNumber.replace(/\D/g, '')}`;
      const confirmationResult = await signInWithPhoneNumber(auth, formattedPhoneNumber, appVerifier);
      setVerificationId(confirmationResult.verificationId);
      setMessage('OTP sent successfully');
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.customData) {
        console.error('Custom data:', err.customData);
      }
      setError(`Error sending OTP: ${err.message}`);
      // Reset reCAPTCHA
      if (window.recaptchaVerifier) {
        try {
          await window.recaptchaVerifier.clear();
          window.recaptchaVerifier = null;
          setupRecaptcha();
        } catch (clearError) {
          console.error('Error clearing reCAPTCHA:', clearError);
        }
      }
    }
  };

  return (
      <div style={{ margin: '20px' }}>
        <h2>Phone Authentication</h2>
        <div id="recaptcha-container"></div>

        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Enter phone number with country code (e.g., +1234567890)"
          value={phoneNumber}
          onChange={(e) => setPhoneNumber(e.target.value)}
          style={{ marginBottom: '5px' }}
        />
        <button onClick={sendOtp}>Send OTP</button>
        {message && <p style={{ color: 'green' }}>{message}</p>}
        {error && <p style={{ color: 'red' }}>{error}</p>}
      </div>
  );
};

export default PhoneAuth;


Things I've tried:
Ensured reCAPTCHA is set up properly: I’ve included a hidden reCAPTCHA widget and am initializing it in the setupRecaptcha function.
Phone number formatting: I’m ensuring the phone number has a valid international format by using +${phoneNumber.replace(/\D/g, '')}.
Checked Firebase project settings: The Firebase project is set up for phone authentication, and I’ve confirmed that the reCAPTCHA domain matches.
Error Description:
I’m able to initiate the OTP sending process, but the following error occurs when the sendOtp function is executed:
FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/internal-error).
What I'm trying to achieve:
I want to send an OTP to the user's phone and verify it using Firebase Phone Authentication in my web extension). However, I am unable to send the OTP due to the error above.
Request for help:
Why am I seeing this error (auth/internal-error) when trying to send the OTP?
Is there any Firebase-specific setting that could be causing this issue in chrome extension?
Are there any common mistakes that I might have missed in the setup for Firebase phone authentication?
I appreciate any help or insights!
I want to send an OTP to the user's phone and verify it using Firebase Phone Authentication in my web extension). However, I am unable to send the OTP due to the error above.
